# nvd3.js Multi Bar Horizontal Chart: how to add a top horizontal axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Is it possible to add a top horizontal axis (yAxis) to a Multi Bar Horizontal Chart of nvd3.js ?

Or to have a top horizontal axis (yAxis) instead of the bottom horizontal axis (yAxis)

Comment: looking for the same answer.  thanks.